# Creating a new collection in Solr using command line

Tags: solr

I know that are a few ways to create Solr collections. One using Solr Admin UI webpage. Another using [Collections API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API)

**But How do I create collection in Solr using COMMAND LINE ?**

Answer (score 6):

Let's suppose you have download and placed the Solr binaries at the location `/opt/apps/solr`, then you can create a collection in the following manner.

```
cd /opt/apps/solr/bin 
./solr create -c {collectionName} -n {configName} -p 8983
```

Done!

Answer (score 5):

Navigate to the folder where you copied solr binary files. And type the following from terminal :
`bin/solr create_core -c name_of_core_or_collection`

This command line utilizes the Collections API for you - to create a new core.

Comment: How to define a directory in which solr is to put this collection?

Answer (score 3):

For creating a collection when you are running in cloud mode, use create_collection command.. i.e.

> solr create_collection -c myCollection